# Include a pdf file as Thesis Cover

Tags: pdf, texstudio, include

I need to include a cover in my thesis. Its is a specific cover from a pdf file. Supposedly using `\includepdf`, the pdf should appear, but it does not.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the only thing you have told us is that you are using texstudio but that is just the editor you use to write the source document it is unrelated to any tex errors.  latex will not silently omit content, if the pdf does not appear there will be an error message in the log file, you should show the input you used and any resulting error.